# Getting error while using win32com module to read mails

Tags: python, win32com

Code to check the Email from outlook, we are getting error on this case , on

> self.*oleobj*.Invoke(dispid, LCID, invkind, 1, index)
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)

```
import win32com.client

ol = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
ns = ol.GetNamespace('MAPI')  # namespace
rootFolder = ns.Folders.Item(1)
# checkFolder = rootFolder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['00-Support'].Folders['001-Checks']
checkFolder = rootFolder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['03-Patching']
messages = checkFolder.items
subject = []
for message in messages:
    print(message.subject)
    subject. Append(message. Subject)
print("--------------")
print(subject[-1])
```

Comment: Which line triggers the error? And are there spaces between "subject." and "Append" in your original code?

Comment: getting error in line 6

Comment: File "C:/Users/x01364907/PycharmProjects/createIncident/ServiceFirst/readMail-FromOutlook.py", line 6, in <module>
    checkFolder = rootFolder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['00-Support'].Folders['001-Checks']

Comment: File "C:\Users\x01364907\Miniconda3\envs\envpy39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 329, in __getitem__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(dispid, LCID, invkind, 1, index)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.', None, 0, -2147221233), None)

Comment: Break it down, and print out the `.Name` property of each folder. eg `print rootFolder.Name`, `inbox = rootFolder.Folders['Inbox']` and `print inbox.Name`. The error is because one of the Folders collections does not contain the folder name you are asking for. `ns.Folders.Item(1)` may not be giving you the root folder you expect.